# autoscrolling loop/circular recyclerViewpager/ normal Viewpager in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am developing an android Online shopping application.

I wish to duplicate the UI of Grofers application.

The landing/Home activity displays horizontal [imageviews[1](http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple18/v4/30/a8/1e/30a81ec8-5631-d984-55af-7f1f900abb4e/screen322x572.jpeg), which auto-scroll after every few seconds. Also the views are circular, for example
if there are 5 images , after the 5th image, the view scrolls to the  first.
I have tried many similar libraries but failed to find the best one.

edit:

looprecyclerViewPager doesn't work in [this](https://github.com/lsjwzh/RecyclerViewPager) library.

How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: what's the problem with libraries you tried? can you share some source code?

Comment: https://github.com/lsjwzh/RecyclerViewPager: loopRecyclerViewPager doesn't work

Comment: @VedprakashKumar any solution found?

Comment: the library I referred to works now.The bug was fixed by the developer. You can try that out.